# How to get my Dark Mode switch to work on each click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building an app with a dark mode switch. It works on the first click, but after that, it works on every *second* click.

*(this snippet shows a checkbox. In the project, it looks like a real switch)*

Any idea how I can get it to work on a single click?

```js
const body = document.getElementById('body');
let currentBodyClass = body.className;
const darkModeSwitch = document.getElementById('darkModeSwitch');

//Dark Mode
function darkMode() {
    darkModeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (currentBodyClass === "lightMode") {
            body.className = currentBodyClass = "darkMode";
        } else if (currentBodyClass === "darkMode") {
            body.className = currentBodyClass = "lightMode";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#darkModeSwitch {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 15px;
    }

.darkMode { background-color: black; transition: ease .3s; }
.lightMode { background-color: #FFF; transition: ease .3s; }

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff89d;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  background: #757575;
}

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"]:before {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="lightMode">

  <div id="darkModeSwitch">
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="darkMode()" title="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why add the click handler to a different element than which you're selecting? You add the click handler to the input but query the parent of the input. Additionally, if you're using a checkbox to represent the state, why not use the checked value of the checkbox? If it's checked then you're in dark mode and if it isn't you're in light mode.

Comment: Hey PizzaCompany88; if any of the answers to this question have helped you, it would be great if you could [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - This will mark your question as solved, helping people finding your question in the future, and reward both yourself and the answer with some reputation

Comment: You can use `change` eventListener instead of `click` eventListener and you can also use label instead of div like `<label id="darkModeSwitch">`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you click on your checkbox, you're adding another eventListener to `darkModeSwitch` - Take your `addEventListener` out of the function and remove the `onclick`

Then, you need to move `let currentBodyClass = body.className;` inside the `darkModeSwitch` function, so that the value is updated each time. Having it outside the function, you're assigning it a value *once* at run time, and then never updating it

Finally, this makes limited sense

```js
body.className = currentBodyClass = "darkMode";
```

Instead, just do

```js
body.className = "darkMode";
```

```js
const darkModeSwitch = document.getElementById('darkModeSwitch');
const body = document.getElementById('body');

//Dark Mode
darkModeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let currentBodyClass = body.className;

  if (body.className === "lightMode") {
    body.className = "darkMode";
  } else if (currentBodyClass === "darkMode") {
    body.className = "lightMode";
  }
});
```

```css
#darkModeSwitch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

.darkMode {
  background-color: black;
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.lightMode {
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: ease .3s;
}

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff89d;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  background: #757575;
}

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"]:before {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="lightMode">

  <div id="darkModeSwitch">
    <input type="checkbox" title="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
  </div>

</body>
```

---

Finally, you might want to consider using [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) when working with an Element's classes, as it will allow you to make use of methods such as [`.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) / [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) / [`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) - Your current method will fail if the Element has more than one class set at a time, while these methods avoid this

```js
let currentBodyClass = body.classList;

if (currentBodyClass.contains("lightMode")) {
  currentBodyClass.add('darkMode');
  currentBodyClass.remove('lightMode');
} else if (currentBodyClass.contains("darkMode")) {
  currentBodyClass.add('lightMode');
  currentBodyClass.remove('darkMode');
}
```

Comment: Nice, Shiny but instead of seeing if the class is strictly equal the actual class I would ask if it has that class, but really nice :)

Comment: Good idea - I've added this section at the bottom

Answer (score 5):

On every click event of the checkbox you are setting a new event listener on the `darkModeSwitch` element, which can be removed

```js
const body = document.getElementById('body');
let currentBodyClass = body.className;
const darkModeSwitch = document.getElementById('darkModeSwitch');

//Dark Mode
function darkMode() {
    
        if (currentBodyClass === "lightMode") {
            body.className = currentBodyClass = "darkMode";
        } else if (currentBodyClass === "darkMode") {
            body.className = currentBodyClass = "lightMode";
        }
    
}
```

```css
#darkModeSwitch {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 15px;
    }

.darkMode { background-color: black; transition: ease .3s; }
.lightMode { background-color: #FFF; transition: ease .3s; }

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff89d;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  background: #757575;
}

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"]:before {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="lightMode">

  <div id="darkModeSwitch">
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="darkMode()" title="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is easier to check using the input type

```
var isChecked= document.getElementById('input[type="checkbox"]').checked;
if(isChecked){ //checked
  //execute code here
}else{ //unchecked
  //execute code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before Answer:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="darkMode()" title="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
```

You call function `darkMode` on every click, and than

```
function darkMode() {
    darkModeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => { // you add event listener
        if (currentBodyClass === "lightMode") {
            body.className = currentBodyClass = "darkMode";
        } else if (currentBodyClass === "darkMode") {
            body.className = currentBodyClass = "lightMode";
        }
    });
}
```

In result of it you will have as many listeners as you click on checkbox.

You need oen from 2 options:

1. `onClick` in html and remove `darkModeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {`
   or
2. remove `onClick` and `darkMode` function and keep `darkModeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {` - this will add a listener and will handle all the clicks

Getting back to answer, there are many working answers, I just want to advice a little on optimization

Simplified demo:

```js
const body = document.getElementById('body');
const darkModeSwitch = document.getElementById('darkModeSwitch');

// put classes into array
const themeClesses = [`lightMode`, `darkMode`];

//Dark Mode
function darkMode() {
  // simply map through it and toggle
  themeClesses.map(str => body.classList.toggle(str))
}
```

```css
#darkModeSwitch {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15px;
        top: 15px;
    }

.darkMode { background-color: black; transition: ease .3s; }
.lightMode { background-color: #FFF; transition: ease .3s; }

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff89d;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  background: #757575;
}

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"]:before {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="lightMode">

  <div id="darkModeSwitch">
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="darkMode()" title="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you click the button you add a new event listener to the switch. So every second time you are clicking the button the dark mode it toggled an even number of times resulting in no change.

An easy way to see this is to add a log in the

```
let eventCount = 0;
function darkMode() {
    console.log("Event was fired for the " + eventCount + "th time!");
    eventCount++;
    darkModeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (currentBodyClass === "lightMode") {
            body.className = currentBodyClass = "darkMode";
        } else if (currentBodyClass === "darkMode") {
            body.className = currentBodyClass = "lightMode";
        }
    });
}
```

The solution is, like the other answers suggest, to remove the addEventListener call in the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is stemming from the fact that you're applying two event handlers to facilitate the context switch, one inline and one via `addEventListener`. In regards to state management, it's a bit more idiomatic to leverage the checkbox `checked` state as your indicator to toggle dark mode.

```js
const body = document.getElementById('body');
let currentBodyClass = body.className;
const darkModeSwitch = document.querySelector('#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"]');

darkModeSwitch.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var isChecked = e.target.checked;
  if (isChecked) {
    body.className = currentBodyClass = "darkMode";
  } else { //unchecked
    body.className = currentBodyClass = "lightMode";
  }
});
```

```css
#darkModeSwitch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}

.darkMode {
  background-color: black;
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.lightMode {
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: ease .3s;
}

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff89d;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"] {
  background: #757575;
}

#darkModeSwitch input[type="checkbox"]:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

#darkModeSwitch input:checked[type="checkbox"]:before {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="lightMode">
  <div id="darkModeSwitch">
    <input type="checkbox" title="Toggle Light/Dark Mode" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple...

```
 //Dark Mode
function darkMode() {
    body.className = currentBodyClass = (currentBodyClass==="lightMode") ? "darkMode":"lightMode";
}
```

If you are performing more than just a "toggle" feature, a bespoke function that will just swap classes out will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `click` event for input `type=checkbox` so you can use `change` eventListener so this is easy way to check using the input type `checked` or `not`.

```js
const body = document.getElementById('body');
const darkModeSwitch = document.getElementById('darkModeSwitch');
//Dark/Light Mode Switch Function
darkModeSwitch.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
  if (darkModeSwitch.checked) {
    body.className = "darkMode";
  }
  else{
    body.className = "lightMode";
  }
});
```

```css
#darkModeSwitch{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.darkMode{background-color: black; transition: ease .3s; color: #FFF}
.lightMode{background-color: #FFF; transition: ease .3s; }
```

```html
<body id="body" class="lightMode">
 
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="darkModeSwitch" title="Toggle Light/Dark Mode">
</label>

<br><br>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</body>
```